# Displaying multi-row array from AJAX in HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm building a mobile app through Cordova and I'm having trouble displaying an array I'm using to get data from a database through AJAX. I've gotten the php working to produce what I think is a properly formatted array but it is getting mangled and turned into "object, object" somewhere along the line.

I'm also not massively sure on actually putting that data into the html since it's my first time doing this in javascript (would normally just use php), but that is less important than getting the bloody data across properly.

HTML/Javascript:

```
<body onload="getList();">
<div class="app">

<div id="output">If you can see this text something has gone wrong. </div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getList(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "***.php",
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("unparsed data"+data);
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            alert("parsed data"+data);

            for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                content = data[x].PID;
                content += "<br>";
                content += data[x].name;
                content += "<br>";
                $("#output").append(content);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus)
        {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        }
    });
};
</script>
</div>
```

The the php file producing the array is

```
$results_array = array();
$results = mysqli_query($db_server, $query); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($results)){
$table_data[]= array("PID"=>$row[1],"name"=>$row[3]);
}
echo json_encode($table_data);
```

Which when run in browser produces

```
[{"PID":"11","name":"testname"},{"PID":"11","name":"Dev2test"}]
```

But when I run the actual app, the first alert inside the ajax success function returns

```
"unparsed data[object Object],[object Object]"
```

But then the second alert doesn't fire, and nothing is appended to the html.

Comment: Have editted my answer multiple times due to confusion, please check revision :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are specifying `dataType: 'json'` in your query the returned response will already be parsed as JSON and so you don't need to use `JSON.parse`.

It is not reaching the second alert as I imagine `JSON.parse(data)` is emitting an error due to data already being an object.

Comment: Turns out the only error I had was the one being caused by trying to parse it when it was already parsed. Removed that and everything is working now, thanks for pointing that out to me!